# How to filter users by role in Gorm?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I found some issues understanding the documentation. I have REST API with Go and I tried to create an endpoint where I need to extract users only by their role. I tried different solutions, but can't achieve what I need. This is what I made and I'm not sure how to continue so I can take the users only by exact role. If someone can help me it will be appreciated, because I can't find more advanced stuff in the documentation.

**The JSON response from this endpoint is:**

```
[
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "CreatedAt": "2020-12-09T14:40:55.171011+02:00",
        "UpdatedAt": "2020-12-09T14:40:55.175537+02:00",
        "DeletedAt": null,
        "email": "h@go.com",
        "password": "$2a$14$KN2wAOnfecAriBW0xeAJke.okEUlcpDHVeuk",
        "bearer": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIs2lhdCI6MTYwNjMwNTEzNn0.J2wBp8ecA9TebP6L73qZ1OZmo02DwQy9vTySt0fil4c",
        "first_name": "H",
        "last_name": "Pro",
        "phone": "353456",
        "salesforce_id": "sfsdddfsdf",
        "webflow_id": "wfwfwfaawfw",
        "Roles": null
    },
    {
        "ID": 2,
        "CreatedAt": "2020-12-09T14:40:55.171011+02:00",
        "UpdatedAt": "2020-12-09T14:40:55.175537+02:00",
        "DeletedAt": null,
        "email": "s@go.com",
        "password": "$2wAOnfecAriBW0xeAJke.okEUlcpDHVeuk",
        "bearer": "eyJhbGiIs2lhdCI6MTYwNjMwNTEzNn0.J2wBp8ecA9TebP6L73qZ1OZmo02DwQy9vTy0fil4c",
        "first_name": "S",
        "last_name": "Test",
        "phone": "3556",
        "salesforce_id": "sfsdf",
        "webflow_id": "wfwfwfw",
        "Roles": null
    }
]
```

**User struct:**

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Email        string  `json:"email"`
    Password     string  `json:"password"`
    Token        string  `json:"bearer"`
    FirstName    string  `json:"first_name"`
    LastName     string  `json:"last_name"`
    Phone        string  `json:"phone"`
    SalesforceID string  `json:"salesforce_id"`
    WebflowID    string  `json:"webflow_id"`
    Roles        []*Roles `gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL;many2many:user_roles;"`
}
```

**Role struct:**

```
type Roles struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Users []*User `gorm:"many2many:user_roles"`
}
```

**The sql query I made and works for my case in Postgre:**

```
SELECT * FROM users
JOIN user_roles ON users.id = user_roles.user_id
JOIN roles ON user_roles.roles_id = roles.id
WHERE user_roles.roles_id = 1
```

**the User struct:**

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Email        string  `json:"email"`
    Password     string  `json:"password"`
    Token        string  `json:"bearer"`
    FirstName    string  `json:"first_name"`
    LastName     string  `json:"last_name"`
    Phone        string  `json:"phone"`
    SalesforceID string  `json:"salesforce_id"`
    WebflowID    string  `json:"webflow_id"`
    Roles        []Roles  `json:"roles" gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL;many2many:user_roles;"`
}
```

**the struct of Roles**

```
type Roles struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Users []*User `gorm:"many2many:user_roles"`
}
```

**the endpoint:**

```
func (h *Handler) GetAllEmployees(c *gin.Context) {
    var users []models.User
    //var roles []models.Roles //the comment here is because I get error message roles is defined but never used
    var roleid int = 1
    //you need to extract roleID from your query string or request body
    
    tx := h.db.DB.
          Preload("Roles").
          Joins("INNER JOIN user_roles ON users.id = user_roles.user.id").
          Joins("INNER JOIN roles ON user_roles.roles_id = roles.id").
          Where("user_roles.roles_id = ?", roleid).
          Find(&users)

    if tx.Error != nil {
      //handle error
    }
    c.JSON(200, users)
}
```

Comment: basically, you want to load `Roles` into each `User` object, and filter users by role ID?

Comment: @EminLaletovic yes, exactly. By now, as you can see from the json I got the Roles as list, because I define Roles as an array I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Based on all the answers below, following things need to happen here:

1. You need to rename `Roles` struct into `Role`
2. You need to load `Roles` for each object
3. Filter users by a specific role ID

First, you need to rename the `Roles` struct to `Role`, and change references to it:

**Role struct**

```
type Role struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Users []User `gorm:"many2many:user_roles"`
}
```

**User struct**

```
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Email        string  `json:"email"`
    Password     string  `json:"password"`
    Token        string  `json:"bearer"`
    FirstName    string  `json:"first_name"`
    LastName     string  `json:"last_name"`
    Phone        string  `json:"phone"`
    SalesforceID string  `json:"salesforce_id"`
    WebflowID    string  `json:"webflow_id"`
    Roles        []Role `gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL;many2many:user_roles;"`
}
```

Next, modify your code a bit. There is one join that is not necessary here:

```
func (h *Handler) GetAllEmployeesByRoleID(c *gin.Context) {
        var users []models.User
        var roleID int = 1
        //you need to extract roleID from your query string or request body
        
        tx := h.db.DB.
              Preload("Roles").
              Joins("INNER JOIN user_roles ur ON ur.user_id = users.id").
              Where("ur.role_id = ?", roleID).
              Find(&users)

        if tx.Error != nil {
          //handle error
          c.JSON(500, tx.Error)
          return
        }  
        
        c.JSON(200, users)
}
```

So, you add `Preload("Roles")` to load all roles that a user can have, as I assumed that, even if you filter by `roleID`, you want to see all roles that a user can have.

You can use `Joins` and `Where` to construct a similar query you already used. A `JOIN` with the `roles` table isn't necessary since you have the needed info in the `user_roles` table.

Comment: i edit the query to fit my needs and the response is null. Also maybe I didn't understand you clear because var roles and var roleID said that they are not used and the IDE mark them as an error.

Comment: by which role ID you want to filter the users? do you pass it to this endpoint method or is it hardcoded?

Comment: I have field for role id in the Roles table with id=1 which I assign it to the user

Comment: if role ID is 1, then hardcode it. Just change it to `var roleID int = 1` or `roleID := 1`.

Comment: I understood now. It still gives me null as a response, which is super strange to me

Comment: I assumed that this is your REST API endpoint method and that you want to pass `roleID` to it. If that is so, it will need to be extracted from `gin.Context`.

Comment: what is null? `Roles` field inside the `User` object?

Comment: what you can also try is to define `Roles` in `User` object as `Roles  []Roles json:"roles" gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL;many2many:user_roles;"`, to see if it will preload the data.

Comment: I still get null as a response, I edit my question so you can see the current version. Could you please take a look? I was also thinking to make something like just Raw Query to make it works with my sql's query but I can't find how to use Joins with Raw

Comment: Just to confirm, you are referring to `Roles` field inside the `User` object still being `nil`? Or are not users found and the `users` variable is `nil`?

Comment: Yes, I referred Roles inside of the User struct and the response I got from the endpoint is null. Also I have some users in the table too, but just got null

Comment: I change the answer based on your info, please tell me if it works or which error it returns, if any.

Comment: Thank you a bunch! It returns what I need :) I accept your answer